# Mojolicious home-test question

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I tried to install Mojolicious-1.90 but didn't pass the t/mojo/home.t test.

```
t/mojo/home.t .............................. 1/5 
#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 27.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = '.cpan'
#     $expected->[3] = 'public_html'

#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 33.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = 'public_html'
#     $expected->[3] = '.cpan'

#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 39.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = '.cpan'
#     $expected->[3] = 'public_html'
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 5.
t/mojo/home.t .............................. Dubious, test returned 3 (wstat 768, 0x300)
```

Is this a bug or could be wrong something else?

With version 1.92 I get the same error:

```
t/mojo/home.t .............................. 1/5 
#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 27.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = 'Mojolicious-1.92'
#     $expected->[3] = 'public_html'

#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 33.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = 'public_html'
#     $expected->[3] = 'Mojolicious-1.92'

#   Failed test 'right path detected'
#   at t/mojo/home.t line 39.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->[3] = 'Mojolicious-1.92'
#     $expected->[3] = 'public_html'
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 5.
t/mojo/home.t .............................. Dubious, test returned 3 (wstat 768, 0x300)
```

Comment: Did you try with the latest Mojolicious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the reason, why the home test didn't pass - it was the setup (`export MOJO_HOME=/home/me/public_html` in my .bashrc).

Answer (score 2):

Try grabbing the file and run the tests yourself:

```
wget "http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SR/SRI/Mojolicious-1.92.tar.gz"
tar -xzf Mojolicious-1.92.tar.gz
cd Mojolicious-1.92
perl Makefile.PL 
    # Checking if your kit is complete...
    # Looks good
    # Writing Makefile for Mojolicious
make test
```

Comment: Also with version 1.92 the test failed.

Comment: are you on a strange setup? Do the other tests succeed? I would just forece the install if I where you ..